# Angular 6 Pass parameter throught effect rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Hello how to pass **payload** parameter from mergeMap to switchMap ? 
I use it in clientservice.checkValideName but would like pass it into sendMessage(data, **payload[1]**) .

I tried many things but nothing works. (another mergemap or map the result of checkValideName to inject the payload)

```
@Effect()  CheckValidatedName$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(CheckValidatedActionTypes.VALIDATED_NAME),
map((action: ValidatedNameAction) => action.payload),
withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromRoot.selectors.getCurrentClient)),
mergeMap(([payload, client]) =>
  this.clientService.checkValideName(client.uuid, payload[0])
),
map((result: any) => result.data),
switchMap((data: boolean) => {
  return of(this.sendMessage(data))
}),
catchError((res: any) => this.catchResponseError(res))
```

);

Answer (score 2):

You could return it as part of the mergeMap response - that's where you lost it in the pipe anyway:

```
mergeMap([payload, client] => {
  // now we have it, and after returning clientServiceCheck, we lose the reference to it
  return this.clientService(checkValidname(client, payload));
})
.map(result => result.data)
```

Instead of that, you want to return both result and data, roughly like this:

```
mergeMap([payload, client] => {
  // now we have it, and after returning clientServiceCheck, we lose the reference to it
  return mergeMap(() => [
    of(payload)
    this.clientService(checkValidname(client, payload)),
  ]);
})
.map([payload, result] => {
  // now we have both
})
```

Comment: ok will update my question with this solution, but it cause me a strange error message

Comment: Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<SBR<boolean>> | Observable<string[]>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<SendBackResult<boolean>> | Observable<string[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
      Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<SBR<boolean>> | Observable<string[]>>'.

Comment: I likely got the syntax wrong, or the exact piping/operators order, typing on the phone will do that for you. I'll look at it when I get home.